# Performance of querying for a string that starts and ends with something

Tags: sql, performance, algorithm

Are there any performance difference in querying a database for some character column starting with something and ending with something?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%something'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like 'something%'
```

Any downsides to choose one approach instead of another? Disregarding the user need for matching the start or end of a word.
The way it is implemented maybe the algorithms differ in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL optimizer will look for an index on column in the second example, and will narrow it down to the records beginning with the characters before the wildcard.   In the first example, it can't narrow it down, so you'll like scan either the index or table (depending on index structure).

Which SQL product are you using?

Comment: You do, and I added postgresql as a tag.   Each SQL version has its own optimizer, and while I can't speak specifically for Postgresql, most SQL optimizers will behave as I described if there is an index on the column...

Answer (score 9):

Instead of creating a new column and index to deal with the

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%something'
```

query, you could create an index

```
CREATE INDEX rev_col_idx ON table (reverse(column) text_pattern_ops);
```

and then rewrite the above query as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE reverse(column) like reverse('%something')
```

which will achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The second one will be faster if you have it alphabetically indexed. Otherwise I imagine they'd be the same.

Comment: And how do i alphabetically index my database? Just performing a reindex in the char column is enough?

Comment: like this: `CREATE INDEX your_index_name ON your_table_name (your_column_name)`

Comment: By default, postgres creates a `b-tree index`, which is good for most alphanumeric search operations.

Comment: No problem. Make sure to accept it if it solves your problem. Also, if you need another reference, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/indexes-types.html

Answer (score 3):

On an additional note, if you really need to support   `%something`.

You could add a new column with the string reversed and then create an index on the reverse of the column, so it becomes `gnihtemos`

Now, if you detect the wildcard at the beginning, reverse the search string and search for the reverse column instead of the primary column.   You'll get the speed benefit of the index, at the cost of additional code to keep the reverse column in sync...