# Performance issue between StartsWith and EndsWith on MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I'm used to two different conditions on the same data generated automatically by EF but only one different stack me by the performance `LIKE 'blah%'`(starts with) execute as well less than 1 second but when am I try to run `LIKE '%blah'` (ends with) this is run so much slowly - more than 40 seconds. Regarding this getting timeout exception by EF, etc.(I know how to extend timeouts) but I just need to know what the differences and how to prevent performance slow down in this small distinction.

Comment: Because the second predicate is nonSARGable. Think about a phone bbok. You want to find all name that start with blah. This is pretty simple, you **scan** through the pages until you find the first entry that starts with blah and you stop after you find the last one. But in that same phone book I now want you to find all names that end with "blah". You have to **seek** every single name in the entire phone book to see if it ends with "blah".

Comment: If we talk about the index on the field - we have a nonclustered index on it

Comment: When you do a leading wildcard search it doesn't matter what index you have. Read my example above and think about how an index is rendered useless in the second one.

Comment: Ok, but I have another example Contains(`LIKE '%blah%'`) execute much longer then StartsWith (~15 seconds ) but less in half then EndsWith

Comment: CONTAINS is a function from fulltext search. That is an entirely different animal.

Comment: @SeanLange Your first comment has the terminology reversed. Finding a name starting with "Blah" corresponds to a _seek_, while a name containing or ending with "blah" requires a complete _scan_.

Comment: @HABO true. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the sargability of the second statement - basically, the index doesn't end up helping at all, as that kind of index isn't designed for wildcard searches to the left of a constant. Imagine if I asked you to give me every word in a dictionary that started with 'blah' - it would be super easy, since items are ordered alphabetically! On the other hand, if I asked you to get me every word that contained 'blah' (but didn't necessarily start with it), you'd be stuck going through every word, doing a pattern match against it.

You may wish to look into [full text indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), as I believe that they are better suited to this sort of task.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for EndsWith performance issue, hotfix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774030/2949734).

```
CREATE INDEX rev_col_idx ON table (reverse(column) text_pattern_ops); -- is not required

SELECT * FROM table WHERE reverse(column) like reverse('%something')
```